# product checkout based on reward points

Tags: extensions, payment, reward-points

I am working on a Webshop where purchases are done based on a points system rather than a dollar value. Each product is assigned a points value and when the customer purchases a product, his points are deducted from the accumulated points over time. Any help to point to the right plugin will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hm, interesting. There are some extensions that implement reward points. Maybe you should start by looking at one of those. As far as I know, there are no extensions that just use points to buy.

Comment: If you have money, take a serious look at Magento Enterprise Edition which provides reward points out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rebuilding Magento to only accept reward points maybe treat the currency as points.

So if something is 40 points, make it $40. Remove all tax and change the currency symbol from dollar to something like points through `System > Manage Currency > Symbols`

Now lastly for paying. I would suggest looking for a good giftvoucher module that allows you to give the customer a certain amount of credit / points.

This is probably the easiest way since it's all visual and requires just a little module for charging customers